# How to make bot print embeds using JSON format

Tags: node.js, discord.js

This is the code, I am trying to make it print embeds like the Carl-bot

```
const Discord = require('discord.js')

module.exports.run = async (bot, message, args) => {
  if(message.deletable) message.delete();
  let message2 = args.join(" ")
  let embed1 = JSON.parse(message2);

  return message.channel.send({embed: embed1});
}

module.exports.config = {
  name: "say",
  description: "test",
  usage: "-say",
  accessableby: "Members",
  aliases: []
}
```

Comment: Could you add an example on what your message would look like?

Comment: Well I have found the solution

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean by json format, like initalizing it with json?

If so you can just do

`const embed = new MessageEmbed({ author: "fff" })`

If you mean making an embed and then filling the details with json you would first make an embed and then you can use the utility functions to set the data

From: https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/examples/embed

```js
// Extract the required classes from the discord.js module
const { Client, MessageEmbed } = require('discord.js');
const embed = new MessageEmbed()
 .setTitle('A slick little embed')
 .setColor(0xff0000)
 .setDescription('Hello, this is a slick embed!');
 message.channel.send(embed);
```

Complete Docs: https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageEmbed